# How to prove the measure of $g(C)$ is 1

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C$ be the cantor set on [0,1] and $f$ is the cantor Lebesgue function. define $g(x)=x+f(x)$, we know that $g$ is strictly increasing, how to show $m(g(C))=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be like this, let $G=\bigcup_{i}I_i$ be the complement of $C$ in $[0,1]$, $I_i$ are open disjoint intervals, $f$ maps each of the $I_i$ to constant, so $g(I_i)$ is merely tranlation of $I_i$ and since $f$ is increasing, $g(I_i)$ are disjoint, hence, $$m(g(G))=\sum m(g(I_i))=\sum m(I_i)= m(G)=1.$$
$$
m(g(C))=2-m(g(G))=1
$$
I do not know if it works or not. Hope it may help.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks, but we should say more carefully that $g(I_k)$ are still disjoint after translation because you see, the quantity of translations are different.

Comment: I think for $i\neq j$, $g(I_i)=f(I_i)+I_i$, now since $I_i$ and $I_j$ are disjoint, WLOG, we may assume $x<y, \quad x\in I_i, y\in I_j$, f is increasing $f(I_i)\leq f(I_j)$(in fact strict inequality), hence  $$x+f(I_i)\leq x+f(I_j)<y+f(I_j), \quad x\in I_i, y\in I_j$$, therefore, they are disjoint.